# Matter.js — How to prevent mouseConstraint to capture scroll events?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, matter.js

I am trying to enable scrolling into a page that contains a Matter.js canvas. I looked everywhere and the recommendation is to add `removeEventListener` so the mouse constraint won't hijack the scrolling event. Unfortunately, I am having no success. How can I enable a scroll?

Thank you in advance!

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/scrolling-event-253k4?file=/index.html)

Code

```
import "./styles.css";
import Matter from "matter-js";

//Fetch our canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("world");

//Setup Matter JS
var engine = Matter.Engine.create();
var world = engine.world;
var render = Matter.Render.create({
  canvas: canvas,
  engine: engine,
  options: {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    background: "transparent",
    wireframes: false,
    showAngleIndicator: false
  }
});

//Add a ball
var ball = Matter.Bodies.circle(250, 250, 50, {
  density: 0.04,
  friction: 0.01,
  frictionAir: 0.00001,
  restitution: 0.8,
  render: {
    fillStyle: "#F35e66",
    strokeStyle: "black",
    lineWidth: 1
  }
});
Matter.World.add(world, ball);

//Add a floor
var floor = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(250, 520, 500, 40, {
  isStatic: true, //An immovable object
  render: {
    visible: false
  }
});
Matter.World.add(world, floor);

//Make interactive
var mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
  //Create Constraint
  element: canvas,
  constraint: {
    render: {
      visible: false
    },
    stiffness: 0.8
  }
});
Matter.World.add(world, mouseConstraint);

// Why is this not working?
mouseConstraint.mouse.element.removeEventListener(
  "mousewheel",
  mouseConstraint.mouse.mousewheel
);
mouseConstraint.mouse.element.removeEventListener(
  "DOMMouseScroll",
  mouseConstraint.mouse.mousewheel
);

//Start the engine
Matter.Engine.run(engine);
Matter.Render.run(render);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a HTML issue. in index.html set the `overflow` to `scroll`

Comment: Nootrix you are a winner. Thank you for the heads-up.